# How to group multiple row values (all float64) where the column values (Artist, Track, and Date) are the same?

Tags: python, pandas

My goal is to display a DataFrame that shows the unique Artist, Track, and Date with corresponding float64 columns (Number of Spotify Streams, Number of Apple Streams, Downloads). Something like this:

```
Artist          Track   Date        Consumption Total Streams   Apple Streams
Billie Eilish   bad guy 3/31/2019   2506        3458105         1449640
Billie Eilish   bad guy 3/31/2019               11233
Billie Eilish   bad guy 3/30/2019   2782        4034374         1629823
Billie Eilish   bad guy 3/30/2019               14567
Billie Eilish   bad guy 3/29/2019   2985        4578589         1772980
Billie Eilish   bad guy 3/29/2019               9673
Billie Eilish   bad guy 3/28/2019   285         1660            1
Billie Eilish   bad guy 3/19/2019               1
```

However, my problem is that I only want one instance of an Artist and corresponding track per date. In the above example, there are >1 dates for each artist and track. My hunch is that I need to find a way to simply add the column values where the artist, track, and date are the same-but have had no success just yet.

I've already tried groupby functions, but the output eliminates the artist and date columns and, instead, gives me all stream numbers per Track (which I'm using as the unique identifier):

```
Track Consumption Total Streams Apple Streams   Spotify Streams
    !!!!!!! 237.0     3644.0    11.0             3633.0
```

Pivot table:

```
pivoted_df = pd.pivot_table(df, index="Track", values=["Consumption", "Total Streams", "Apple Streams", "Spotify Streams", "Spotify Premium Streams", "Ad Spotify Streams", "Downloads", "Revenue" ], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Comment: Can you also add an example dataframe before the `expected output`

Comment: can you please write which groupby functions you tried, and also make your input and output columns consistent (spotify streams is not present in your input)

Comment: A group by would work here. I doubt that you did the group by correctly. Can you please show us what you used to attempt it?

Comment: looks like you need `df.groupby(['Artist', 'Track']).sum()` ?